# node.js - zlib compression (RFC 1950)

Tags: node.js, zlib

Is there a way in node.js to create a zlib compressed stream (RFC 1950)?
The deflate-funciton creates a deflate stream and not a zlib stream, which is not what i need.

I need to compress minecraft NBT-chunks this way to store them in MCA-region files. Minecraft won't accept deflate streams...

Comment: Wild guess, what about the [zlib built in module](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html)?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum As mentioned in the question, deflate does not what I need. But if it's possible with the built in module, let me know how ;)

Comment: Use `zlib.Gzip` instead of `zlib.Deflate`..?

Comment: it needs to be a zlib stream, not a deflate or gzip stream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think it doesn't?  `zlib.Deflate` creates a zlib-wrapped (RFC 1950) deflate (RFC 1951) stream.  `zlib.DeflateRaw` creates a raw deflate stream (just RFC 1951).

Is this [Minecraft 1.3 Region File Format](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Region_file_format) the format you are referring to?

Comment: Van Coding can you check which one do you need ? I believe `zlib.Deflate` creates a zlib stream.

Comment: I think it is indeed not the problem of the zlib function. Minecraft's just very sensitive to its input NBT data. But I'm still not sure where the problem is :D